# won't send mail when reading string from file, but want when is string defined in source file

Tags: c#, image, sendmail, rtf

I'm trying to send mail with many images inside of it body. Everything work fine when is html text written to string inside of source file (.cs), but when i try to read same text which i already write to some external file, mail want show images in body it's just put borders (instead of images) and real images put in attach.

For converting from richtextbox to html i use [RTF-Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter) with command **Rtf2Html.exe file.rcf**

How to read from external file text that will show in body of mail that will appear as it appear when i write it "manually" in source code?

Here is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading;
using AE.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public void SendEmail()
{

 System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
            try
            {
                m.From = new MailAddress("your.email@gmail.com", "Display your name");
                m.To.Add(new MailAddress("some.email@gmail.com", "Display"));
                m.Subject = "Test subject";
                m.IsBodyHtml = true;
                // m.Body = "Dont need this!";

                FileStream fs = new FileStream("root.jpg",
                                   FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment a = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(fs, "C:\\root.jpg",MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

                 m.Attachments.Add(a);
                /*
                 **This working when i put two images inside of code section in string "str" it send
                mail with images inside of body**
                */
                string str = "<html><body><h1><p><a href=\"http://www.google.hr\" target=\"_blank\">www.google.hr</a></p><h1>Picture</h1><img src=\"cid:image1\"><h1>First text</h1><img src=\"cid:image2\"><br/><h1>Second text</h1></body></html>";

                /*
                **If i read from file to string and send mail it will show images as attach ("source.html")
                have same text as in above string "str"**
                */

               //   string str = File.ReadAllText("source.html");     

                AlternateView av =
                             AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str,
                             null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
                LinkedResource lr = new LinkedResource("file1.jpg",
                             MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
                LinkedResource lr2 = new LinkedResource("file2.jpg",
                             MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

                lr.ContentId = "image1";
                lr2.ContentId = "image2";

                av.LinkedResources.Add(lr);
                av.LinkedResources.Add(lr2);
                m.AlternateViews.Add(av);

                sc.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                sc.Port = 587;
                sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your.email@gmail.com", "yourpassword1");
                sc.EnableSsl = true;
                sc.Send(m);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: No need to show your 'using' statements

Comment: i would consider hosting those images somewhere on line and just putting them in your HTML as <img src="yourLink"/>

Comment: @Thousand thanx i will try that can you put some code for linking images?

Comment: <img src="www.somewebsite.com/someFolder/someFile.Jpg" width="42" height="42">

Comment: @Thousand thanks but i already created editor for images .. i create dekstop application which sand emails ... how do i put some relative link to images? Can i put image in attachment and link to them from body?

Comment: im not sure about that, but i dont see why you dont just upload those images to some online location and link them like that

Comment: @Thousand ok i will try that ... i didn't use those technic cause those mails are important, so i need to put all things inside of body